# css background color transparent only on some width

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has a background color

```
.custom {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50000px;
    z-index: 30;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: rgba(153,153,153,.95);
    color: white;
}
```

but this is in all of the div width and height.
Is there any way to make it transparent for the first 24px and then the color start without making any other div.
What i mean is this.

The first 24px of height and full width of the div should be transparent.
Then the rest of the height and width should have the background color.

Comment: try css gradient

Comment: @TemaniAfif any code sample?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios check the duplicate question ;) and all the related links you will get many examples